# how to a call static function (eg: static navigationOptions) from another function in react native

Tags: react-native

how can i call a static function (`static navigationOptions`) from any other function in react native?

It fails when using the `this` keyword, but is it possible to render `static navigationOptions` again by calling it?

Comment: Please add your trial as code (i.e. separated by a blank line, indented with 4 positions).

Comment: What is your intent? why are you trying to call navigationOptions? Are you trying to pass any params or are you trying to add navigation bar button to the left or right? Kindly include the code which you have used.

Comment: @ManjuBasha i think that navigationOptions function is called once when the page loads. I have an conditional headerLeft property inside navigationOptions and it is based on a state param.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change navigation options dynamically, try like this

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
return {
  title: navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'A Nested Details Screen'),
};
};

this.props.navigation.setParams({otherParam: 'Updated!'})
```

Another method

```
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const {state} = navigation;
  return {
    title: `${state.params.title}`,
  };
};

ChangeThisTitle = (titleText) => {
   const {setParams} = this.props.navigation;
    setParams({ title: titleText })
}
```

call `this.ChangeThisTitle('your title')` wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

They only way to achieve it is using navigation params. So set your headerleft property flag or value using setParams. That will solve the issue. Below mentioned code should be used in your class.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
    let buttonView = 
        <TouchableOpacity style={navItemStyle} activeOpacity={0.7} onPress={() => { params.logoutClick() }}>
            <Text style={navItemTxt}> Logout</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity >

    return {
        title: 'Home',
        headerLeft: params.showHeaderLeft && buttonView
      };
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        showHeaderLeft: this.props.headerFlag, 
        //headerFlag used above is your value and showHeaderLeft is the name of the param
    });
}
```